# Reading PHP code using file_get_contents

Tags: php

The file_get_contents function doesn't seem to be able to read PHP code from .php files. It seems to ignore everything after a `<?php` tag.

Why might be that?

Comment: what the error you get ? some code

Comment: No error. It's just that the returned value seems to be empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess it isn’t [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) but the way you print the content. Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to have the content encoded properly when putting it out into an HTML document:

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('file')), '</pre>';
```