# file_get_contents not extracting full file contents

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

I m using the php function file_get_contents to parse a php file. But it seems that as soon as it is reading the php tags the file_get_contents is malfunctioning.

I checked the function with a normal text file, its functioning perfectly. But even if it finds php tags in a text file, the file is being half read. How can i find a way to get the full contents.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the **textual content** of the PHP file? Or are you trying to execute the code within that file?

Comment: parse the textual content

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading PHP code using file\_get\_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576248/reading-php-code-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: Is the file local? Or are you trying to get a remote file? How did you check that the content is not read? Echoing it to a browser my trick you because of the `<` char in `<?php`

Comment: yea i m echoing it to the browser. so how do i overcome < char problem??

Comment: htmlspecialchars or <pre>...

Comment: Then i'll just put these 2 comments in an answer. Please accept it :)

Comment: the displaying on the browser is ok.. but then the array which i am getting after the parsing is returning blank values.. i m sending argument to the functions as given below.. $this->allData = token_get_all(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file))); $this->parseFile(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file))); how can i break this problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the file local? Or are you trying to get a remote file? How did you check that the content is not read? Echoing it to a browser might trick you because of the `<` char in `<?php`

Use `htmlspecialchars` or `<pre>` to view the whole text. Or just look at the source of the page.

Comment: the displaying on the browser is ok.. but then the array which i am getting after the parsing is returning blank values.. i m sending argument to the functions as given below.. `$this->allData = token_get_all(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)));  $this->parseFile(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)));` how can i break this problem??

Comment: What array? what does parsing mean? Can you show us the code for `token_get_all` and `parseFile`?

Comment: oh, sorry. Don't know why I've read it as a method on your $this object... I haven't worked with that since I don't even remember. But I do remember that it's pretty buggy. Maybe it will help to post a block of text/php code with which you have that problem.